# EF4 and Creating new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework, and my first bit of code already seems incorrect, or at least, not what I expected.

I have generated my entity objects from the database. One of my tables is `WebUser`.  So I know have an entity object `WebUser`. The database uses an `Identity` column named `WebUserID` that is also the primary key for the table.

However, the `CreateWebUser` method has the following signature...

```
public static WebUser CreateWebUser(global::System.Int32 webUserID, 
                                    global::System.String userName, 
                                    global::System.String password, 
                                    global::System.String emailAddress)
```

Why is it asking for the `WebUserID`? This can't be inserted into the database.

Comment: You know, you can just do `var newUser = new WebUser()`, set whatever you need/like, and then just `yourDBContext.WebUsers.AddObject(newUser)`, or whatever your table name is instead of `WebUsers` :)

Comment: I can't seem to find a DBContext out of all the code generated. I think I'm going to scrap the EF approach for this project. I think I'm going to use Castle ActiveRecord. It's a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `webUserID` or keep it default.
But when you want to add two or more WebUsers,the `webUserID` can be use for set the order of items.

```
db.CreateWebUser(2,"The Second Recored","2","2");
db.CreateWebUser(1,"The First Recored","1","1");
db.SaveChanges();
```

Whick one will be insert to the database first?The answer is whose `webUserID` is smaller will insert to the database first.

Comment: Good to know. I don't have a SaveChanges() method though. It seems CreateWebUser and EntityKeyPropertyName are the only available options.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896331.aspx), you should set the ID to 0. It will be updated by EF when you call `Context.SaveChanges()`.

You can also use [`Context.CreateObject<WebUser>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468073) or (as suggested by the doctor) `var newUser = new WebUser()` to create a new entity and omit the ID while setting the other properties.

Comment: I don't seem to have a Context available. All the samples I see use this.  I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but my edmx file seems to have been generated poorly. I have my 5 entities from my database, but I don't have any of the functionality that should be there.

Comment: @JeffReddy You should have it. After you generated the model, go into the YourModelName.Designer.cs file, open the 'Contexts' region and voila, there is your context with constructors (possibly looks a bit like `public partial class YourDatabaseEntities : Object Context...`). Then you can do `var context = new YourContext();` and enjoy all the delete/update/add operations (and more) :)